# Linux locking file when opening it (like in windows)

Tags: linux, file, locking

Is there a way on a Linux system to have ST check if a file is already opened by another user () and if so not open the file and notify the user?

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: scala & java, but i'm searching for a solution in the file system definions... thanks